# Determine whether or not the vector V is in the kernel of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question as follows 

Matrix A\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1& 2 &1\\0 & 1 & -1 &-1 \\ 1 & 2 & -3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

Vector V
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 0\\ 1 \\-1
\end{bmatrix}

I am wondering how is it possible for V to be in the Kernel of A if the size of A and V are different to each other?

Comment: Hint: what is the definition of the kernel of a matrix?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

A vector $\mathbf{x}$ is in the kernel of a matrix $A$, if $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, where the right-hand side is the zero vector. So you only need to...?

---

> I am wondering how is it possible for V to be in the Kernel of A if the size of A and V are different to each other..

The matrix is $3 \times \color{blue}{4}$ which is compatible with multiplying with a $\color{blue}{4} \times 1$ (column) vector.

But if you are confused about this question, you should probably grab your textbook and carefully check the definition of *kernel of a matrix* before trying this exercise.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean

Comment: Can you compute $A\mathbf{x}$, the product of the matrix $A$ with the vector $\mathbf{x}$? If that product is $\mathbf{0}$, the zero vector, then the vector $\mathbf{x}$ is in the kernel of the matrix $A$.

Comment: Yes the answer for the product is (0,0,0).. is that the answer? since AX = 0 for it it be in the kernel ?

Comment: If the answer was the zero vector then indeed: the kernel of a matrix consists of all vectors which are _mapped_ to the zero vector, by multiplication with the matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the clarification.. my text book doesn't cover it in a nice way which caused the confusion!

Comment: Careful: I didn't check your calculations before, but check the first entry of the product again (or see if you have any typos in the question), because now I get $(\color{red}{4},0,0)$